# Read JSON File in node.js/discord.js with custom string

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem again with my JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
        "GuildID": {
            "10": {
                "RoleID" : 72872978374937894
            },
             "GuildID": {
            "11": {
                "RoleID" : 72872978374937894
            }
 }
```

10 and 11 are the numbers I want to read.

Now I want to get the role ID with this code:

```
let rang = xp[message.guild.id][message.author.id].level
let lol = rang
console.log(rank[message.guild.id][lol].RoleID)
```

The XP JSON Files output is 10, but I got the error, that lol is undefined

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your snippet just isn't finished but your JSON isn't formatted correctly, there are two closing `}` missing, it should look like this

```
{
    "GuildID": {
        "10": {
            "RoleID": 72872978374937894
        },
        "GuildID": {
            "11": {
                "RoleID": 72872978374937894
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps you should give us more code tho, because I can't see a level property here for example (plus I assume `GuildID` is a placeholder for an actual guild ID like `123456789012`), otherwise accessing via `[message.guild.id]` won't work but again, I need more code in order to say if that is the case or not

Comment: Yeah it is. Sorry I forgot to add that. I just want to know how to get thr RoleID